# What shall i do to install pip correctlly?

Tags: python, linux, pip

[image: I tried the following things]

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: make sure you're in the folder that holds the file. might you need a sudo

Answer (score 0):

You have to have "requirements.txt" file in the same folder where you run this command "`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`"

Try to type "`ls -lah`" and provide output here.